# Writing synchronous unittests for Rx v2 Flowable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm converting my project from Rx v1 to Rx v2, and I'm currently in the process changing of some of the v1 `Observable`s to v2 `Flowable`s.

(Its in Android project with unittests written in Groovy using Spock)

Normally I would just override the Schedulers using a hook. I can still do this in v2 by registering scheduler handlers. This makes the `Observable`s synchronous by always using the (new?) `Schedulers.single()`. However, the `Flowable`s are still asynchronous because of the back pressure mechanic(?).

I tried resolving that using the following:

```
Flowable<LogEntry> flowable = Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<LogEntry>() {
    @Override
    void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<LogEntry> emitter) throws Exception {
        for (def log : logs) {
            emitter.onNext(log)
        }

        emitter.onComplete()
    }
}, FlowableEmitter.BackpressureMode.NONE);
```

But that still makes them asynchronous.

I've overriden the schedulers like this:

```
RxJavaPlugins.reset()
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
    @Override
    Scheduler apply(Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
        return Schedulers.single()
    }
})

RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
    @Override
    Scheduler apply(Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
        return Schedulers.from(new Executor() {
            @Override
            void execute(Runnable command) {
                command.run()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I can't seem to figure out why the `Observable`s behave synchronous like this, but the `Flowable`s do not (beside the backpressure mechanic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Schedulers.single()` is a single-threaded asynchronous scheduler. You need `Schedulers.trampoline()` to remain on the same thread.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the replacement of v1's `immediate` Scheduler. I'll give it a go as soon as I get home (forget to push it, the agony!)

Comment: While we are on that topic, might it make sense to add that fact to the documentation?

Comment: Which documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.java#L102 and maybe somewhere where a transition from v1 to v2 is described?

Comment: But single's doc already mentioned "single-thread backed": https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.java#L118